# Image click of RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, networking, android-recyclerview, click

I know that there are already questions on this, but the format which I follow for my code is different so I am unable to find the answer to the question.
When I click on my RecyclerView item which includes TextView and ImageView, I want to show the image in a DetailActivity.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/framelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="pritish.sawant.com.photogallery.MainActivity">
</FrameLayout>
```

fragment_photo_gallery.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="pritish.sawant.com.photogallery.PhotoGalleryFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/loading_indicator"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:text="Hi" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:src="@drawable/image1">

</ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_detail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="pritish.sawant.com.photogallery.DetailActivity">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/detailimageview"
            tools:src="@drawable/image1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setTitle("Photo Gallery");
    fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment=fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.framelayout);
    if(fragment==null){
        fragment=new PhotoGalleryFragment();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.framelayout,fragment).commit();
    }
}
}
```

Photo.java

```
package pritish.sawant.com.photogallery;

public class Photo {

private String title;
private String author;
private String authorId;
private String link;
private String image;
private String tag;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public String getAuthorId() {
    return authorId;
}

public void setAuthorId(String authorId) {
    this.authorId = authorId;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getTag() {
    return tag;
}

public void setTag(String tag) {
    this.tag = tag;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Photo{" +
            "title='" + title + '\'' +
            ", author='" + author + '\'' +
            ", authorId='" + authorId + '\'' +
            ", link='" + link + '\'' +
            ", image='" + image + '\'' +
            ", tag='" + tag + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

FlickrFetchr.java

```
package pritish.sawant.com.photogallery;

import android.net.Uri;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class FlickrFetchr {

private static final String TAG = "FlickrFetchr";
private List<Photo> photoList = null;
private String baseUrl="https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne";

public  String getData(String url){
    BufferedReader bufferedReader=null;
    try {
        URL url1=new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url1.openConnection();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
        bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            stringBuilder.append(line+"\n");
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    finally {
        if(bufferedReader!=null){
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}

private String buildURL(String searchPhoto, String lang, boolean match){
    return Uri.parse(baseUrl).buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("tags", searchPhoto)
            .appendQueryParameter("tagmode", match ? "ALL" : "ANY")
            .appendQueryParameter("format", "json")
            .appendQueryParameter("lang", lang)
            .appendQueryParameter("nojsoncallback", "1").build().toString();
}

public List<Photo> fetchPhotos(String searchPhoto,String language,boolean matchAll){
    String url=buildURL(searchPhoto,language,matchAll);
    return downloadGalleyItem(url);
}


//To receive the json format
public List<Photo> downloadGalleyItem(String url){
    photoList=new ArrayList<>();
    Photo photo=new Photo();
    String jsonString=getData(url);
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");

        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            photo.setTitle(jsonObject1.getString("title"));
            photo.setAuthor(jsonObject1.getString("author"));
            photo.setAuthorId(jsonObject1.getString("author_id"));
            photo.setTag(jsonObject1.getString("tags"));

            JSONObject jsonMedia =jsonObject1.getJSONObject("media");
            String imageUrl=jsonMedia.getString("m");
            photo.setImage(jsonMedia.getString("m"));

            //we are changing _m to _b so that when image is tapped we get biigger image
            photo.setLink(imageUrl.replaceAll("_m.","_b."));
            photoList.add(photo);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return photoList;
}
```

}

RecyclerItemClickListener.java

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener extends RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener {

private static final String TAG = "RecyclerItemClickListen";

interface OnRecyclerClickListener{
    void onItemClick(View view,int position);
    void onItemLongClick(View view,int position);
}

private final OnRecyclerClickListener listener;
private final GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetectorCompat;

public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final OnRecyclerClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
    gestureDetectorCompat=new GestureDetectorCompat(context,new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            View childView=recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());
            if(childView!=null && listener!=null){
                listener.onItemClick(childView,recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            View childView=recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());
            if(childView!=null && listener!=null){
                listener.onItemLongClick(childView,recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
            }

        }
    });
}

public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent){
    if (gestureDetectorCompat!=null){
        boolean result=gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        return result;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

PhotoGalleryFragment.java

```
public class PhotoGalleryFragment extends Fragment implements RecyclerItemClickListener.OnRecyclerClickListener{

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
public ProgressBar progressBar;
public List<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<>();


public PhotoGalleryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo_gallery, container, false);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(),recyclerView,this));

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    setUpAdapter();
    new FetchTask().execute();
    return view;

}

private void setUpAdapter() {
    //isAdded checks whether fragment has been added to the activity
    if (isAdded()) {
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new PhotoAdapter(photos));
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Item Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),DetailActivity.class);
    //what should i pass in putExtra of intent
    //intent.putExtra("IMAGE",photo.getLink());
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Item Long Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private class PhotoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView textView;

    public PhotoHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    }

    public void bindItems(Photo photos1) {

        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(photos1.getImage()).into(imageView);

        textView.setText(photos1.getTitle());


        //  Glide.with(getActivity()).load(photos1.getImage()).into(imageView);
    }
}


private class PhotoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotoHolder> {

    private List<Photo> galleryItems;

    public PhotoAdapter(List<Photo> galleryItems) {
        this.galleryItems = galleryItems;
    }

    @Override
    public PhotoHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        return new PhotoHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PhotoHolder holder, int position) {
        Photo photos2 = galleryItems.get(position);
        holder.bindItems(photos2);



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return galleryItems.size();
    }
}

private class FetchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Photo>> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (photos.size() == 0) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Photo> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return new FlickrFetchr().fetchPhotos("android", "en-us", false);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Photo> photos1) {
        super.onPostExecute(photos);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        photos = photos1;
        setUpAdapter();
    }
}

}
```

DetailActivity.java

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.detailimageview);
    int img_id;

    if (savedInstanceState != null ){
        img_id = getIntent().getIntExtra("IMAGE",0);
        imageView.setImageResource(img_id);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In onItemClick of PhotoGalleryFragment what should i pass in intent.putExtra and how should i retrieve that in DetailActivity's ImageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In onItemClick you can pass Like this

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Item Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),DetailActivity.class);
    //what should i pass in putExtra of intent
    intent.putExtra("IMAGE",photos.get(position).getLink());
    startActivity(intent);
```

In DetailsActivity you can retrieve it by

```
 if (getIntent().getStringExtra("IMAGE") != null) {
            imageurl = getIntent().getStringExtra("IMAGE");
        }
```

Comment: Can you please post the imageurl.